# Creating an XOR Class to Implement a Full Adder

Tags: ruby, xor

I've tried a few different approaches including creating a separate NANDGate class, and using NOR Gates, but I really cannot figure out where I am going wrong in my approach.  My value for the adder output keeps returning as a boolean and the carryout result is incorrect for certain inputs, which I imagine is because the issue lies in the XOR class I have.  If anyone can put me in the right direction it would be highly appreciated.  *Note I'm very unexperienced with Ruby this is my 2nd time coding in it*

```
class Circuit
   # constructor method
   def initialize(in1, in2)
      @in1, @in2 = in1, in2
   end
end

class AndGate < Circuit

   def cir_func()
      (@in1 && @in2)
   end
end

class OrGate < Circuit

   def cir_func()
      (@in1 || @in2)
   end
end

class NotGate < Circuit
   def initialize(in1)
      @in1 = in1
   end

   def cir_func()
      (not @in1)
   end
end

class NandGate < Circuit

  def cir_func()
    (not (@in1_ && @in2_))
  end

end

class XOrGate < Circuit
  def initialize(in1, in2)
    @in1_ = in1
    @in2_ = in2
  end

  def cir_func()
    a0 = AndGate.new(@in1_, @in2_).cir_func()
    a0not = NotGate.new(a0).cir_func()
    a1 = AndGate.new(@in1_, a0not).cir_func()
    a1not = NotGate.new(a1).cir_func()
    a2 = AndGate.new(a0not, @in2_).cir_func()
    a2not = NotGate.new(a2).cir_func()
    o0 = AndGate.new(a1not, a2not).cir_func()
    o0not = NotGate.new(o0)
    return o0not.cir_func()
  end
end

class Mux_2to1 < Circuit

  def initialize(in1, in2, ctr1)
    @in1_ = in1
    @in2_ = in2
    @ctr1_ = ctr1
  end

  def cir_func()
    inv_ctr = NotGate.new(@ctr1_).cir_func()
    a0 = AndGate.new(@in1_, inv_ctr).cir_func()
    a1 = AndGate.new(@in2_, @ctr1_).cir_func()
    o0 = OrGate.new(a0, a1)
    return o0.cir_func()
  end
end

class Mux_4to1 < Circuit

  def initialize(in1, in2, in3, in4, ctr1, ctr2)
    @in1_ = in1
    @in2_ = in2
    @in3_ = in3
    @in4_ = in4
    @ctr1_ = ctr1
    @ctr2_ = ctr2
  end
  def cir_func()
    a0 = Mux_2to1.new(@in1_, @in2_, @ctr1_).cir_func()
    a1 = Mux_2to1.new(@in3_, @in4_, @ctr1_).cir_func()
    o0 = Mux_2to1.new(a0, a1, @ctr2_)
    return o0.cir_func()
  end
end

class FullAdder < Circuit

  def initialize(in1, in2, carryIn)
    @in1_ = in1
    @in2_ = in2
    @carry_ = carryIn
  end
  def cir_func()
    a0 = XOrGate.new(@in1_, @in2_).cir_func()
    o0 = XOrGate.new(a0, @carry_)
    a1 = AndGate.new(@in1_, @in2_).cir_func()
    a2 = AndGate.new(a0, @carry_).cir_func()
    o1 = OrGate.new(a1, a2)
    return o0.cir_func(), o1.cir_func()
  end
end


def Boolean(string)
  return true if string== true || string =~ (/(true|1)$/i)
  return false if string== false || string.nil? || string =~ (/(false|0)$/i)
  raise ArgumentError.new("invalid value for Boolean: \"#{string}\"")
end

puts "Please enter input 1 for adder:"
input_1 = gets()

puts "Please enter input 2 for adder:"
input_2 = gets()

puts "Please enter carry in for adder:"
carryin_ = gets()

x = FullAdder.new(input_1, input_2, carryin_)
output, carryOut = x.cir_func()
puts "The result for the adder is: #{output} and the carry out is: #{carryOut}"
```

Comment: You should use bitwise operators (`&`, `|`, `~`) instead of logical operators (`&&`, `||`, `!`) or keywords (`and`, `or`, `not`) if you want integer return values.

Comment: Note that `gets` returns a string. You probably have to convert the input to a number / boolean (there's an unused method `Boolean` in your code)

Answer (score 0):

Please make sure the next time you break down your code into smaller chunks and test them in isolation. This will help you pinpoint the problem. Since these logical gate stuff is bringing back memories I could not help myself and implemented it on my own and wrote a lengthy answer:-)

I have made some improvements (I'd call it that way :-)) to your code:

Since you have different numbers of inputs I'd NOT make your parent class `Circuit` take a specific number of inputs and then override to change that number. Either remove the parent class (my preferred way) or make it accept a variable number of inputs. This has some benefits but also drawbacks (need to access the inputs as `inputs[0]` and so on. You could work around this by providing accessors):

```
class Circuit
  def initialize(*inputs)
    @inputs = inputs
  end

  def call
    raise "Please implement in #{__FILE__}"
  end

  def inspect
    "#{self.class.name}: #{inputs.join(', ')} => #{call}"
  end

  private

  attr_reader :inputs
end
```

Because you opted for a parent class I implemented some samples using this technique:

```
class AndGate < Circuit
  def call
    inputs.inject do |memo, input|
      memo &&= input
      memo
    end
  end
end

class OrGate < Circuit

  def call
    inputs.inject do |memo, input|
      memo ||= input
      memo
    end
  end
end

class NotGate < Circuit
  def call
    !inputs[0]
  end
end
```

The `AndGate` and `OrGate` supports an arbitrary number of inputs:

```
p AndGate.new(true, true, true).call # => true
```

If you don't like this... then you can restrict the inputs...

Also note that I renamed `cir_func` to `call`. This is for two reasons:

- I don't know what *cir* stands for
- I don't like abbreviated method names (*func*)

but of course you can change this as you like.

Now you can write some tests to verify the behavior:

```
require 'minitest/autorun'
class GateTest < Minitest::Test
  def assert_table(klass, table)
    table.each do |inputs, outputs|
      gate = klass.new(*inputs)
      assert_equal outputs, gate.call, "Expected #{klass} to convert #{inputs} to #{outputs}"
    end
  end
end

class AndGateTest < GateTest

  def test_gate
    table = {
      [false, false] => false,
      [false, true] => false,
      [true, false] => false,
      [true, true] => true
    }
    assert_table(AndGate, table)
  end

end
class OrGateTest < GateTest

  def test_gate
    table = {
      [false, false] => false,
      [false, true] => true,
      [true, false] => true,
      [true, true] => true
    }
    assert_table(OrGate, table)
  end

end

class NotGateTest < GateTest

  def test_gate
    table = {
      [false] => true,
      [true] => false,
    }
    assert_table(NotGate, table)
  end

end
```

I've opted for a superclass test which provides a helper method to assert that a logical table.

With the basic gates in place you can start to build the composite ones:

```
class NandGate < Circuit
 def call
   NotGate.new(
    AndGate.new(*inputs).call
  ).call
 end
end
```

And some more complex ones:

```
class XOrGate < Circuit
  def call
    OrGate.new(
      AndGate.new(
        NotGate.new(inputs[0]).call,
        inputs[1]
      ).call,
      AndGate.new(
        inputs[0],
        NotGate.new(inputs[1]).call
      ).call
    ).call
  end
end
```

And the tests for those:

```
class NandGateTest < GateTest

  def test_gate
    table = {
      [false, false] => true,
      [false, true] => true,
      [true, false] => true,
      [true, true] => false
    }
    assert_table(NandGate, table)
  end

end

class XOrGateTest < GateTest

  def test_gate
    table = {
      [false, false] => false,
      [false, true] => true,
      [true, false] => true,
      [true, true] => false
    }
    assert_table(XOrGate, table)
  end

end
```

And finally we can implement the full-adder with its test:

```
class FullAdderGate < Circuit
  def call

    sum = XOrGate.new(
      inputs[2],
      XOrGate.new(
        inputs[0],
        inputs[1]
      ).call
    ).call

    carry = OrGate.new(
      AndGate.new(inputs[0], inputs[1]).call,
      AndGate.new(
        XOrGate.new(inputs[0], inputs[1]).call,
        inputs[2]
      ).call
    ).call

    [carry, sum]
  end

end
```

You could shrink this method by assigning/re-using intermediate results but I could not think of clever names so I did not do this:-)

```
class FullAdderGateTest < GateTest

  def test_gate
    table = {
      [false, false, false] => [false, false],
      [false, false, true] => [false, true],
      [false, true, false] => [false, true],
      [false, true, true] => [true, false],
      [true, false, false] => [false, true],
      [true, false, true] => [true, false],
      [true, true, false] => [true, false],
      [true, true, true] => [true, true],
    }
    assert_table(FullAdderGate, table)
  end

end
```

**Attention:**
For your code you want to make sure that you convert the input that you read via `gets` to booleans. You already have some code there with `Boolean`.

Answer (score 0):

This is a half adder that works. You could make a full adder like this without too much complexity - perhaps. I don't feel there's a good reason for 30 pages of code when it comes to what is arguably the most basic, simple thing a computer does.

```
#resulting values, do not set
sum0 = false
carry = false


#binary (set)
a = true
b = true

if a ^ b        #this is the equivalent of XOR
  sum0 = true
  carry = false
end

if a && b
  sum0 = false
  carry = true
end

#expand from here...
```